# I am getting this error i dont know why "'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom'"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-dom

Even though I used Routes instead of switch still its showing the same error ,I installed react dom using the command npm install -S react-router-dom. The code is below

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import Home from './Home';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route} from 'react-router-dom';


function App() {
return (
>     <Router>
>     <div className='app'>
>       <Switch>
>         <Route path='/'>
>           <Header/>
>           <Home/>
>         </Route>
>       </Switch>


>     </div>
>     </Router>




export default App;
```

The Error that is showing is
'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom'
And
'Route' (imported as 'Route') was not found in 'react-router-dom'

Comment: Which version of `react-router` and `react-router-dom` are you using?

Comment: Also shouldn't `Switch` be imported from `react-router` instead of `react-router-dom`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using react router v5 as switch is is not in v6. In that case the import for switch is following:

```
import { Switch } from "react-router";
```

You are importing it from `react-router-dom` while it should be from `react-router`